# Why is a lab PSU not suitable for driving a laser diode directly?

Tags: power-supply, laser-diode

I'm looking to drive some laser diodes (50mW) at very modest powers (50%), using simple circuits no doubt less sophisticated than most lab PSUs.

Why does [this site](https://www.photonics.com/Articles/Driving_Diode_Lasers_A_Straightforward_Procedure/a32187) say it's not an option? I understand temperature changes, noise, pulses, spikes, inductances and so on, as the page itself describes.

But, since I'll have a lot if headroom, with a rough and ready constant current source that does that it says on the tin I guess, plus more than enough heat dissipation, what's the problem? How much noise and inductance can there  be?

Comment: One concern that immediately springs to mind is spikes when first connecting the device. Many LAB PSUs have pretty big output caps that will need to be drained before the current limit kicks in.

Answer (score 9):

The section "Not an option" states:

> It is important that diode lasers always have a regulated driver in either automatic current control or automatic power control operation. A standard laboratory power supply is not suitable for driving them directly.

You have referenced the second sentence which states that "a laboratory power supply is not suitable". The preceding sentence says that a PSU with automatic current control *is* suitable - but hints that it is not ideal.

[image]

*Figure 1. An extract from the randomly chosen [U-LD-650543A](http://www.uocnet.com/pdf/LD/U-LD-650543A..pdf) datasheet showing the power versus forward current curves at various temperatures.*

We can see that, for this laser diode, that at constant current, say 15 mA, the output power will fall from about 2.5 mW to 1 mW as temperature rises from 25°C to 40°C. This will protect the diode at the expense of variation in output power as temperature varies so at least you'll save the laser but your application may not work reliably.

In short, a voltage-limited lab power supply would not be able to protect the laser, a current-limited supply will protect it but not give constant power and a power-regulated PSU will give the optimum performance.

Your linked article goes on to say (under "Seeking constant power"):

> Automatic power control employs a monitor diode integrated into the  laser package for feedback. Lasers with integrated monitor diodes are available in three configurations, all with the common terminal connected to their housing, which is often electrically connected to ground. The output from an integrated monitor diode is not suitable for calibration. At a given output power, the monitor current may vary by a factor of 10 from laser to laser.

So the best way to control the laser is to monitor the optical power output using a built-in photo-diode. There are three common arrangements.

[image]

*Figure 2. Three different monitoring diode arrangements. **LD** = laser diode. **MD** = monitoring diode. Source: [Driving Diode Lasers - A straghtforward procedure](https://www.photonics.com/Articles/Driving_Diode_Lasers_A_Straightforward_Procedure/a32187) (OP's link).*

The schematic of Figure 2 shows each of the three arrangements. Note that in each case the LD is forward biased and the MD is reverse biased as is normal in photo-diode applications. The voltage across the MD will increase with increasing incident light levels. The op-amp monitors this voltage and as it rises (indicating increasing laser power) it will reduce the drive to the LD transistor. The circuit will stabilise at the designed power output level.

The three options shown are:

1. P-type: the MD anode and LD cathode share the common terminal. The package common terminal is connected to the lower rail of a single rail supply.
2. N-type: the MD cathode and LD anode share the common terminal. The package common terminal is connected to the upper rail of a single rail supply.
3. M-type (mixed): the cathodes share a common terminal. This option requires a split-rail supply.

The important point here is that the MD is used to regulate the **power** to the LD.

[image]

*Figure 3. The U-LD-650543A pinout.*

The pinout of my randomly chosen laser diode shows that it is an N-type. Note a difference in terminology: PD, photodiode, versus MD, monitoring-diode, in Figure 2.

Comment: but why is this necessary and what does the PD   actually do? and what if Adafruit supplies you with one with two leads?  This only describes common solutions not the problem why CC won't work well.

Comment: FWIW this is a low power  fairly well-defined Laser and *easy to use* compared to a 10W laser. or a 50W laser for thermal design issues and efficacy effects.

Answer (score 3):

### **short answer**

Laser Diode resistance is highly non-linear with several modes for thermal runaway. THat's why you are advised not to use a simple constant current limiter until you understand why not.

You should use an internal optical feedback diode (PD) with low ESL reverse clamped power regulation. Or design one that works (warning) or monitor the laser temperature with a bonded forward diode ( not OK  slower ... warning but OK for LEDs)

### how does it work? ( so you can understand why)

Consider a laser diode with a forward threshold of < 1 V and a rated forward current of say 1.2 with a differential resistance inversely related to power rating.  An optical cavity is a form of positive feedback with losses and when the excitation threshold for "lasing" is reached it turns from an LED into a resonant mode LASER ( "light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation")

The **[Lasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#Terminology)** current now jumps to about 10x typically if regulated, as well as power slightly more than this and still, has a positive differential resistance that is positive temperature coefficient (PTC) of R vs Temp. leading to more power and thermal runaway. If the junction temperature rises in milliseconds due to poor heatsink resistance, and sufficient current supply at some voltage, you have a blown laser diode.

Meanwhile, the junction threshold voltage could have a PTC or NTC characteristic depending on type.  Consider a negative temperature coefficient (NTC). This is defined by the Schockley Effect and depends on chemistry, temperature gradients in the junction and other stuff like diode Ideality Factor.  Let's say it reduces the diode saturation threshold voltage Vt, 100mV for every 100'C rise in current or -1mV/'C. I am assuming you know that all diodes based on Ideality factor have some   Vt vs log(If) constant and when that slope begins to drop (by some defined amount) it is beginning to saturate and operate as a dim LED only and the size of the chip (which is a factor in power rating) controls the crystal/electrode interface bulk differential resistance ( similar to ESR but not quite) This is the part that also has the PTC while the crystal diode has the NTC. So if you had a voltage source current limited and series R a drop in Vf or Vt , the series R now has more voltage drop to increase current resulting possible thermal runaway with the bulk resistance also increasing.

### So what is the best practice?

So if you have a tiny diode reverse biased to catch an internal reflection and an extra lead out for this sensor, you can detect the light emission current * R = Voltage in xxx mV to use as feedback for tight low ESL current regulation of your laser.

Then you compute your thermal resistance Case to Ambient to ensure the junction temp rise is minimized on the design because Laser diodes might last 1000 hours maxed out in the 1~10W range because Arhennius Law in Chemistry says aging rate of the material doubles approx every 10 deg 'C.  So you want to keep it as cool as possible with CPU-like heatsink methods.  Otherwise you have a short-lived disposable pointer.

Now I will only mention that if the Tj junction temp rises to fast for your control system to respond or too hot, a frequency mode hop can reduce efficacy and now your feedback photodiode level drops and your feedback tries to drive even more current and poof another burnt laser diode (unless you detect/regulate the above intentionally.)

if you are familiar with positive feedback oscillators or how negative feedback to to much delay result in unstable controls or overshoot then you appreciate the joke [next](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#cite_note-Biographical_Memoirs-6).

The acronym LOSER, for "light oscillation by stimulated emission of radiation", would have been more correct.

Comment: +1 for the lol alone ty. PS you know too much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you would read the fine details on that website, it states that temperature feedback and regulation is more important than current regulation.

For a given limited current the laser diode heats up and can have subtle shifts in wavelengths which cause an increase in diode temperature.

A bench top power supply has current and voltage regulation, but cannot sense the laser diode temperature and roll back the current if the laser diode gets hot. It is assumed the power source is well filtered DC with plenty of source current.

You need a bona-fide laser supply that includes temperature sensing of the laser so it can reduce the allowed drive current. A conventional bench top power supply will get the laser running, but the laser may burn up within minutes.

A quote from that site, plus its URL.

> An often overlooked factor in handling diode lasers is the influence
>   of temperature on the relationship between optical output power and
>   operating current. While the threshold current raises with temperature
>   the optical output power and differential efficiency decrease. The
>   driver circuit thus should have a safety feature that ensures that a
>   significant temperature increase will not destroy the laser.

[Link to laser article](https://www.photonics.com/Articles/Driving_Diode_Lasers_A_Straightforward_Procedure/a32187)