# Laser Diode Feeding

Tags: diodes, current-limiting, laser, laser-diode, laser-driver

Edit: [Laser diode info page](https://www.rpmclasers.com/product/ep1550-adf-b-1550nm-adf-laser-diode/)

I have a basic question about laser diodes. For a 14-pin butterfly package as shown below. I know that I need to control the current going in to the laser diode, but I don't know about the voltage. Should the voltage on anode(11,13) to cathode(3,12) be regulated? Or is it okay if the voltage is below the maximum ratings after the current is limited? Thanks in advance.

[image: type2biast]
[image: absolute ratings]

Comment: Just FYI, note that "Absolute Maximum Ratings" which you currently have shown in your question, has a specific meaning (search for previous questions mentioning that phrase). They are *not* the maximum values which you should expect to use in normal operation. If you edit your question to add a link to your specific datasheet, you might get more advice.

Comment: Check out the action over at [Why is a lab PSU not suitable for driving a laser LED directly?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398471/why-is-a-lab-psu-not-suitable-for-driving-a-laser-diode-directly).

Comment: No, you do not as long as you are below the maximum rated voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LD voltage must stay below the max rated voltage for the laser diode. It will *if* you control the current to the LD and the laser isn't damaged.

Usually you monitor the voltage, and the current and control on the photodiode (which is power output) and shut things down if the voltage or the current approach the maximums.

You'll likely need a controller on the TEC as the laser needs to be cooled and the wavelength dependence is about 0.3 nm per degree C.

Comment: So I understand the forward voltage that is referred as "2 V" at max does not require any control. It is enough when the input of the laser diode is below 2V with control of the current going in to the laser diode.

Comment: Yes.  Your laser should be shipped with a test datasheet. You'll see what the V I relationship of your laser is. Run the laser at low power, confirm that you see the same characteristics and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The PD is used to regulate lasing current in the LASER diode and the TEC current is regulated by temp using the thermistor to minimize junction temp rise assuming more than adequate heat transfer in the design.

Ultra low ESL due to -2V abs damage threshold for diode max. It is improved by reducing slew rate of current during shut down.

PD=Photo Diode= " Monitor Diode" used for regulation of intensity. Peltier cooler (PEC and thermistor for Thermal negative feedback for temp regulation.  If these are foreign to you, better master these, before trying a LASER like this.

Comment: Word sallad! Did op ask about either PD, TEC, ESL or slew rate? No. No, he did not.

Comment: @winny et al (2) Let me remind you , when you think **word salad**, ask yourself , Why do you not understand?.  Do your re-search.   This is critical.   ALL OF THE ABOVE is necessary to control V and I for a simple laser as shown in the diagram.  You have a lot to learn.

Comment: PD=Photo Diode= " Monitor Diode"  used for regulation of intensity.  Peltier cooler (PEC and thermistor for Thermal negative feedback for temp regulation.  This is the correct short Answer.  Read more , doubt less. and dont worry about  my typos like your "sallad."

Comment: The clarification in the comment is a big help, @Tony. Why not add them into your answers as standard. It would really help the quality of your answers which while they may be technically excellent are very tough reading, particularly for novices. If you're under time pressure then just answer fewer questions. You could also create a wiki page for all your favourite initialisations and acronyms. I think there are a few of us prompting you but reception seems to be filtered out somewhere.

Comment: You only need to read the datasheets not come here to ask. I give hints that can be time consuming to explain to the novice. But this redundant if it must be clearly defined in App Notes and Datasheets. I only suggested the acronyms in the image to imply the  servo loops that control LASER power.  This forum will never become like Wiki without major front end changes and professional peer review.  perhaps an automated Wiki link suggestion popup could save time to insert definitions of terms might be added to the site's javascripting

Comment: What this site (and ALL students of learning i.e. all of us) sorely needs?... is a self-help tutorial. How to find simple answers already on this site or in any search engine.  e.g. read top five hits for details that would be redundant to repeat here.  https://www.google.com/search?num=50&client=firefox-b-ab&q=how+to+regulate+laser+power+peltier+photodetector&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHsILS6eLdAhWF5YMKHaWYCqkQBQgpKAA&biw=1664&bih=819 and if not good enuf, add keywords to improve results.  the best answer depends on the best question, which this one for example., does not deserve.

Comment: Understood all of it but _neither_ answered OPs question. I see a lot of this in your answers. A lot of words but few of them on topic.

Comment: THen you need to figure out what you need to learn so that it is not confusing.  eg " PD is used to regulate lasing current " understood? ok. next " the TEC current is regulated by temp using the thermistor " got that? ok next.....what is stopping you from comprehension?   WOrd Salad is offensive only to yourself.  Do I need to shorten the sentences to 18 words or less?